# Converting CSV file to JSON Array JS

Tags: javascript, json, csv

I have this CSV file for a sankey diagram and i want to reform it in JSON because my function uses JSON format but although i need to read from CSV

The CSV file is Like this :

```
source,xPos,target,value
user1,0,user2,4
user2,1,user3,4
user1,0,user3,2
user5,user4,2
```

and the JSON file form supposed to be like this so my code will be able to read it.

```
{
    "nodes":[
        {"node":0,"name":"user0","xPos":0},
        {"node":1,"name":"user1","xPos":0},
        {"node":2,"name":"user2","xPos":1},
    ],
    "links":[
        {"source":0,"target":2,"value":2},
        {"source":1,"target":2,"value":2},
        {"source":1,"target":3,"value":2},
}
```

Ignoring the names and the links cuz the dont mach in the example but it is just an example.

Comment: Your JSON is missing a closing brace.

Comment: @Mr. Polywhirl   I already mentioned it is only an example although i can read from this JSON file but im not able to read from the CSV. and im using 

     d3.csv();

Comment: @Chis what do you mean by not able? what errors are you encountering?

Comment: @Craicerjack This is how i read from the JSON file 


`d3.json("sankey.json", function(error, graph){
  
    
  window.width = 1200; //determines the width of the dra
  sankey
      .nodes(graph.nodes)  
      .links(graph.links)
      .layout(32);`

and i need to convert it to the reading from CSV

Comment: Do you want CSV to Json on client side or server side ?

Comment: @Luke P. Issac for the moment it is locally.

Comment: But you are using client side javascript or server side javascript ?

Comment: @LukeP.Issac Server-side

Answer (score 0):

There is no easy way to do this. You would need to implement custom logic as seen below.

```js
var csv = "source,xPos,target,value\nuser1,0,user2,4\nuser2,1,user3,4\nuser1,0,user3,2\nuser5,user4,2";

var json = csv.split('\n').reduce(function(result, line, index) {
  if (index > 0) { // Skip header.
    var data = line.split(',');

    if (data.length === 4) { // Skip rows with incomplete columns.
      var containsSourceNode = result.nodes.some(function(node) { return node.name === data[0]; });
      if (!containsSourceNode) {
        result.nodes.push({
          node : result.nodes.length,
          name : data[0],
          xpos : data[1]
        });
      }

      var containsTargetNode = result.nodes.some(function(node) { return node.name === data[2]; });
      if (!containsTargetNode) {
        result.nodes.push({
          node : result.nodes.length,
          name : data[2],
          xpos : data[1]
        });
      }

      result.links.push({
        source : result.nodes.filter(function(node) { return node.name === data[0]; })[0].node,
        target : result.nodes.filter(function(node) { return node.name === data[2]; })[0].node,
        value : data[3]
      });
    }
  }

  return result;
}, {
  nodes : [],
  links : []
});

document.body.innerHTML = '<pre>' + JSON.stringify(json, null, 2) + '</pre>';
```

---

#### Example using a cache.

```js
var csv = "source,xPos,target,value\nuser1,0,user2,4\nuser2,1,user3,4\nuser1,0,user3,2\nuser5,user4,2";

var json = csv.split('\n').reduce(function(result, line, index) {
  if (index > 0) { // Skip header.
    var data = line.split(',');

    if (data.length === 4) { // Skip rows with incomplete columns.
      var containsSourceNode = result.cache[data[0]] != null;
      if (!containsSourceNode) {
        result.nodes.push(result.cache[data[0]] = {
          node : result.size++,
          name : data[0],
          xpos : data[1]
        });
      }

      var containsTargetNode = result.cache[data[2]] != null;
      if (!containsTargetNode) {
        result.nodes.push(result.cache[data[2]] = {
          node : result.size++,
          name : data[2],
          xpos : data[1]
        });
      }

      result.links.push({
        source : result.cache[data[0]].node,
        target : result.cache[data[2]].node,
        value  : data[3]
      });
    }
  }

  return result;
}, {
  nodes : [],
  links : [],
  cache : {},
  size  : 0
});

delete json.cache;
delete json.size;

document.body.innerHTML = '<pre>' + JSON.stringify(json, null, 2) + '</pre>';
```

Comment: You can also create a node cache on the side for quick lookup.

Comment: this could work very well but in case i have a external csv file and i need to linke it with 'd3.csv(filename.csv)' 

how should this work !?

Comment: Your data, in it's raw form, does not translate to JSON very easily. I don't think you can use a library for this case. The best you can do is pre-process it into json on the server. After that, you can load it into `d3.json()`. You are over-complicating things.